# python - for loop to input multi dataframe to function

Tags: python, list, pandas, function, dictionary

The original dataset looks like this:

```
df.head()

id  name      level zone_id time
0   Light Rain  1   79      2018-01-01 08:00-10:00
1   Medium Rain 2   1       2018-01-02 09:00-14:00
2   Light Rain  1   79      2018-01-02 09:00-11:00
3   Medium Rain 2   1006    2018-01-01 08:00-09:00
4   Medium Rain 2   1       2018-01-03 10:00-13:00
5   Light Rain  1   1006    2018-01-03 22:00-0:00
6   Light Rain  1   1       2018-01-03 18:00-21:00
```

I would like to seperate each zone_id to different dataframe and then clean them.

I get the zone list from another table and get:

```
 zone_list
['1006',
'79',
'1']
```

Then I use for loop to get multiple dataframe

```
for i in zone_list:
    globals()['df_'+i] = df[df.zone_id == i]
```

Then i need to clean these data by using a function like this:

```
def clean_data(data):
    ...
    return data
```

What i want to do is to put all dataframe df_1, df_79 and etc to this function and output multi dataframe.

So far if i do `clean_data(df_1)` it works prefectly. but i dont know how to make a loop for all these dataframe.

What i want is

```
df_79.head()

id  name      level zone_id time
0   Light Rain  1   79      2018-01-01 08:00
2   Light Rain  1   79      2018-01-02 09:00

df_1.head()

id  name      level zone_id time
1   Medium Rain 2   1       2018-01-02 09:00
4   Medium Rain 2   1       2018-01-03 10:00
6   Light Rain  1   1       2018-01-03 18:00
```

etc.

I was trying to use dict but still have no idea as well.

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you considered using a list instead of setting globals in this terrible manner?

Comment: Or for that matter, just a normal `groupby` directly in pandas?

Comment: `list = [df_1,df_79]
for x in list:
    x = clean_data(x)`   but this way doesnt not change the x value? if i check df_79, it still shows the original. @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to hold a variable number of variables. Combined with [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you can utilise a dictionary comprehension. For example:

```
dfs = {key: group.pipe(clean_data) for key, group in df.groupby('zone_id')}
```

[`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) is just a way of passing your dataframe through a function in a format which facilitates method chaining.

You can then access a dataframe for `79` via `dfs[79]`. I strongly recommend you do not use named variables such as `df_79` as these can be hard to track and manage. In addition, I recommend you do not use `globals()` unless there is a specific requirement, which is rarely the case.

Comment: that helps a lot! I am still wondering how to extract dfs into different dataframes since i want to merge them with another dataframe.

Comment: `how to extract dfs into different dataframes`: I'm not sure what you need here. But it seems straightforward, for each group, you can use `dfs[group]`, e.g. `dfs[79]`, `dfs[1]`, `dfs[1006]`, etc.

Comment: So my next step is to merge dataframes. ```dfs[79].merge(cancels[79], left_on = 'date', right_on = 'date',how = 'inner')```gives me no result but ```dfs[79].merge(cancel_79, left_on = 'date', right_on = 'date',how = 'inner')``` is successfully merged. if i put cancels[79] as a dataframe by ```cancel_79 = cancel[cancel.zone == '79']```

Comment: ```cancels = {key: group for key, group in cancel.groupby('zone_id')}``` which is another dataframe that also group by zone_id. yeah i guess so, i might ask a new one. just fyi.